# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel returns weird strings on Motorola devices

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel to get the String of the phone type of the user (1 --> home, 2 --> mobile, 3 --> work, etc.).
Everything seem to work fine on most devices, but on Motorola devices the returned strings are some weird chars I can't even type here (looks like Korean/Japanese/Thai). The locale of those devices is English and users also can't understand those weird strings.

My code is straight forward:

```
return ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, "").toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting a pre defined label of a contact is pretty direct, however, if the user has set a custom label, then it's not direct, you can try the follwing to get the correct label :

```
int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            String label = context.getResources().getString(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabelResource(type));
            if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("Custom")){
                label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
            }
```

You can now directly use the **label** string.

Answer (score 1):

In this way, in `typeName` you will get the standard or the custom label. (`crPhones` is the cursor that iterate the numbers associated to a single contact):

```
String label = crPhones.getString(crPhones.
        getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
int type = crPhones.getInt(crPhones.
        getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
String typeName = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
        getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, label).toString();
```